# OS X: How do I check for a specific WiFi network and mount network drives on startup

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, osx-leopard

At home I use my MacBook Pro on my own WiFi network and routinely mount several volumes from a RAID attached to my AirPort Base station. I like to have my MBP automatically mount the volumes on startup.

In the past I have dragged their locations into my startup items so they would auto-mount, but this causes problems when I startup my MBP on other WiFi networks where my RAID is not available. Finder *searches and searches* for the drives and sometimes hangs.

What I would like to do is somehow have my MBP detect which WiFi network its on at startup and only if connected to my home network attempt to mount the RAID volumes.

Is this possible with Apple/Shell script or some 3rd party software?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) is a really cool peice of software for having your computer figure out where it is based upon a large number of criteria (which WiFi is visisble, which monitor is hooked up, etc.) and then take actions (including mounting network disks) based upon that information.

I use it for switching certain settings based on whether I am at home or at work, and it works really, really well.

Best of all, it's free.

Comment: This worked really well, thanks! I like the different rules that can be set for different criteria. Another reason why I love Mac developers.

Comment: ControlPlane is a maintained Fork of MarcoPolo http://www.controlplaneapp.com/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Home and Away](http://maccrafters.com/home_and_away/).  Works for me.  I just have a script that gets run to mount the drives on my home network when it knows I am there.

Comment: I just looked at MarcoPolo (from the other answer) it looks to have more features...might be the better way to go

Comment: Home and Away looks totally suitable, but I went for MarcoPolo for the additional features. Thanks for you help!